# Create collections through iterating a JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make an event-based calendar by iterating through an array of json objects with individual dates using javascript.

What I want to achieve is a new structure from these objects, where i get the year from the object and make that a unique key which can contain multiple months as keys retrieved from the objects, which then again can contain multiple days as keys retrieved from the objects, which again contains multiple objects... phew..

F.ex., say I have this json file:

```
"objects": [
{
    "dateTime": {
        "date": "2016-12-24"
    },
    "values": {
        "value1": "some value",
        "value2": 700
    }
}, {
    "dateTime": {
        "date": "2016-12-24"
    },
    "values": {
        "value1": "other value",
        "value2": 3100
    }
}, {
    "dateTime": {
        "date": "2016-12-25"
    },
    "values": {
        "value1": "random value",
        "value2": 300
    }
}, {
    "dateTime": {
        "date": "2017-01-02"
    },
    "values": {
        "value1": "value",
        "value2": 100
    }
}]
```

Now I want to iterate through each object and make something like this:

```
[{
    "2017": [{
        "january": [{
            "monday": [
                object
            ]
        }]
    },
    "2016": {
        "december": [{
            "saturday": [
                object,
                object
            ],
            "sunday": [
                object
            ]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

So I don't want any duplicates of any object which is set as key. What path should I go for? I've been looking into Map, WeakMap, Set and WeakSet, but I just can't figure out how to do this properly.

Comment: Did you look at `reduce`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Thanks, that got me a little further. But I'm struggling to make this nested structure.. With reduce I'm only able to do like this: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840445/js-reduce-array-to-nested-objects)