# Reducing an Array of unknown length to a nested Object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take an array and create a nested object from it, where each item in the array, is a property of the previous item.

I think `reduce` is the way to do this, but I find `reduce` hard to grasp, and everything I try I get stuck knowing how to push into the next level.
[JS: Reduce array to nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840445/js-reduce-array-to-nested-objects) is a similar question, but I still can't work it having tried many variations of that.

```
const myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

// Intended Output (note, the staticCount is always 1)
{
    one: {
        staticCount: 1,

        two: {
            staticCount: 1,

            three: {
                staticCount: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some jobs call for `Array.prototype.reduceRight`:

```js
const myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three']

const nestNode = (acc, key) => {
  acc.staticCount = 1
  return { [key]: acc }
}
console.log(myArray.reduceRight(nestNode, {}))
```

**Let's take a look at `reduceRight` (and, by extension, `reduce`):**

I moved the iterator function definition out of the call to `reduceRight` to make the example easier to talk about (see `nestNode`).

`reduce` and `reduceRight` are similar:

1. Each takes two arguments, an iterator function and an initial value for that function's accumulator. The second argument is optional, but I will ignore that here.
2. Each iterates over all of the items in the array on which they're called, calling the iterator function for each item in the array with four arguments, the accumulator, the current item in the array, the current iteration count and the whole array on which you called `reduce`. The last two arguments are not relevant here (and I rarely use them).
3. The first time the iterator function is called, it will be passed the second argument you provided to `reduce` or `reduceRight` (the initial accumulator value). Afterwards, it will be passed whatever was returned by the iterator function in the previous step.

**Because I think `reduce` (and by extension `reduceRight`) are powerful abstractions that are worth understanding, I'll step through the first two steps in the code example:**

1. On the first step in the iteration, our iterator function is called like this: `nestNode(acc = {}, key = 'three')`. Inside `nestNode`, we add a `staticCount` property to `acc` and set it to `1`, giving us `acc = { staticCount: 1 }`. Then we create and return a new object with a property named `'three'` that has a value equal to `acc`. The value returned by `nestNode` in the first step is `{ three: { staticCount: 1 } }`, and `nestNode` will be called with this value in the second step.
2. On the second step in the iteration, our iterator function is called like this: `nestNode(acc = { three: { staticCount: 1 } }, key = 'two')`. Again, we add a `staticCount` property to `acc` and set it to `1`, giving us `acc = { three: { staticCount: 1 }, staticCount: 1 }`. We then create and return a new object with a property named `'two'` that has a value equal to `acc`. The value we return is `{ two: { three: { staticCount: 1 }, staticCount: 1 } }`. Again, this value will be used in the next step.

I'll skip the last step, since I hope that taking a look at the first two steps, in detail, is enough to clear things up a little. If you have other questions or still find something unclear or confusing, please let me know.

`reduce` (and `reduceRight`) are powerful, flexible tools that are worth learning and becoming comfortable with.

As a coda, I'll leave you with the return value of the iterator function after each step:

1. `{ three: { staticCount: 1 } }`
2. `{ two: { three: { staticCount: 1 } }, staticCount: 1 }`
3. `{ one: { two: { three: { staticCount: 1 } }, staticCount: 1 }, staticCount: 1 }`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thanks, Mark, I fixed that issue.

Comment: @Tex this is great, thanks - I learnt a lot from your answer!  Every answer (at time of writing) was a correct solution, so I have to accept one and I opted for the one I felt the most readable.

Comment: After reading through all your comments I actually do think this answers the question best and uses reduce for what reduce in the _correct_ way.

Answer (score 2):

With thanks to Tex for making me replace `reverse().reduce()` with `reduceRight`:

`['one', 'two', 'three'].reduceRight((a, c) => ({[c]: { staticCount: 1, ...a }}), {});`

Comment: This is probably the solution I'd use, most of the time. It's ever so slightly slower than my `reduceRight` example (because of the object-spreading and creation of an additional new object as opposed to an assignment to an existing object), but it's also very compact and easy to read. I'd only consider one of the faster examples if I had reason to believe that the difference in performance would be a problem in my application.

Answer (score 2):

`reduce`, like `map`, will loop over each item in an array and return a result. The key difference is that `map` will return an array of equal size to the original with any modifications you made. `reduce` takes what’s called an `accumulator` and returns that as the final result.

`reduce()` takes two parameters:

1. a `function()`
2. a starting value for `accumulator`

The `function()` you provide is given three values:

1. value of `accumulator`
2. value of current item in array
3. value of current iteration (not used in this example)
4. value of original array (not used in this example)

The most important thing to understand about the `accumulator` is that it will become the value of whatever your `function()` returns, and your function **ALWAYS** has to return something, otherwise `accumulator` will be undefined on the next loop.

Following the solution to your problem is a basic example using `reduce`.

#### Solution

```js
const myArray = ['one','two','three'];
const result = {};

myArray.reduce((accumulator, num) => {
  accumulator[num] = { staticCount: 1}
  return accumulator[num];
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

## Performance

The `reduce` solution provided here can perform 7.6 million operations per second, vs. `reduceRight` at 2.2 million operations per second.

https://jsperf.com/reduceright-vs-reduce/

#### Basic Example

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Reduce will assign sum whatever
// the value of result is on the last loop

var sum = numbers.reduce((result, number) => {
  return result + number;
}, 0); // start result at 0

console.log(sum);
```

#### Another example

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Here we're using the iterator, and
// assinging "too much" to sum if there
// are more than 4 numbers.

var sum = numbers.reduce((result, number, i) => {
  if (i >= 4) return "too much";
  return result + number;
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: The performance difference here may be due to the reduce() version relying on external state (result). The reduceRight() version seems more functional.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your use case. Personally, I’d take 7.6 million over 2.2 million, even if reduceRight is the more appropriately named function for this task.

Comment: In a case like this, I'd reach for `reduceRight` unless I knew this was going to be running in a hot path where the difference matters. I'd do this because I think the `reduceRight` version is easier to comprehend and is using the `reduce` abstraction correctly, rather than as a glorified `forEach`. If, later, I realized that the performance was an issue, I'd consider using the more efficient `reduce` variant. Thanks for sharing the performance tests - the results surprised me as well.

Comment: Regarding (premature) optimization: There is no guarantee that the `reduce` solution will be faster than the `reduceRight` solution in the future. It may even be slower at some point. I sometimes fall prey to the temptation to unnecessarily squeeze every last drop of performance out of my routines, but it has often been the case that the compilers end up outsmarting me in the end, finding ways to beat or match performance gains I've realized through tricks that may make my code more difficult to reason about than if I'd picked the more fitting abstraction from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Just use reduce. It works because objects are passed by reference.

```js
const myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const newObject = {};

myArray.reduce((acummulator, element) => {
  acummulator[element] = {
    staticCount: 1
  };
  return acummulator[element];
}, newObject);

// Intended Output (note, the staticCount is always 1)

console.log(newObject);
```

Read about reduce [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 1):

The trick would be not to start from an empty object, but from some declared variable. Then just pass the newly child down as the aggregate for the next recursion.

The reference gets updated, and you can then print the root again.

```js
const myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const root = {};
myArray.reduce( (agg, c) => {
  agg[c] = { staticCount: 1 };
  return agg[c];
}, root );

console.log( root );
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved with a recursive function:

```js
const createObj = (keys) => keys.length > 0 && ({
  [keys[0]]: {
    staticCount: 1,
    ...createObj(keys.slice(1))
  }
});

console.log(createObj(['one', 'two', 'three']));
```

Comment: Nice work! Here's my go at a recursive solution: `const createObj = ([head, ...tail]) => head !== undefined && (tail.length === 0 ? {[head]:{staticCount:1}} : {[head]: {staticCount: 1, ...createObj(tail)}})`